# How acknowledgement for persistent message works with Virtual Topics?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, middleware

If am not wrong

When producer publishes a persistent message on a topic then broker first store message(s) in persistent store (let kahadb) and then send an acknowledgment back to producer.

So how will it work in case of Virtual Topic with a logical queue because message will be stored for queue as well in kahadb?

(Assume there is a durable subscriber on the topic)

Thanks

**Edit**:
I will explain my use case.... A producer is publishing onto a topic and there are 5 subscribers, I want that out of these 5, first 3 get message normally and for remaining 2 only one of them get message, so I thought Virtual Topic can help in this and for those 2 subscribers I will make them listen to logical queue rather than topic... but I want to know what will happen to persistent message if broker crashes/restart in between....what will happen to persistent message that has been sent to broker...its possible that before replication to queue's persistent store, broker stops. So is there any acknowledgement mechanism in place as in case of direct producer to broker.

Comment: You have some terminology mixed up here.   Producers produce to queues.  Publishers publish to topics.  Although a publisher can publish persistent messages, they are not persisted the way they are when you use a producer.  Although I believe there is still a block, I've seen some odd behavior when using Virtual Topics and a queue that has exceeded a storage/memory limit and the publisher continuing to publish.  So it leads me to believe it isn't as straight forward as producer to queue and acks from the broker back to the publisher work differently for publishers than they do with producers.

Comment: @ErikWilliams thanks correcting me for terminology, I have edited appropriately now.

Comment: So what's the actual question here?  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @TimBish I have given details in edit of my question......

Comment: So you intend to have the final two attached to the same queue and compete for messages?  Or make one of them an exclusive consumer?

Comment: Sorry meant to continue that response: Messages that are persisted to queues from virtual topics work the same way as messages persisted to queues from a normal producer.  Sorry, I can't definitively answer your question on how the acks work on topics with virtual topics configured.

Comment: @ErikWilliams I want them to compete for message